# Try to get string from a dict but it returns me a tuple

Tags: python-3.6

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot. source_list is a list and record is dict. I don't know why RefID is a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma at the end of the line.  That creates the tuple...in this case, a tuple of length 1.

Simplified example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x
1
>>> x = 1,
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> x
(1,)
```